# jsdom/cheerio considerably alter html

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom, cheerio

I am trying to scrape a website and I'm having issues with both jsdom and cheerio dramatically changing the html they get. Most notably, they remove some tags such as table/tr/td tags, etc

simply having a local file say 1.html and doing:

```
// with cheerio -> or equivalent with jsdom
var $ = require('cheerio').load(fs.readFileSync(path));
fs.writeFileSync('2.html', $.html());

# bash
$> diff 1.html 2.html

.....

<                       <tr><td colspan="5"><a id="stats" name="stats"></a><div class="titlebar1" style="margin-top: 12px;margin-bottom: 4px;"><h2>Stats</h2><div class="element"><img src="img/element/10.png" /></div><div class="elementborder"><img src="img/elementborder.png" /></div></div></td></tr></table></td></div>

---
>                       <tr><td colspan="5"><a id="stats" name="stats"></a><div class="titlebar1" style="margin-top: 12px;margin-bottom: 4px;"><h2>Stats</h2><div class="element"><img src="img/element/10.png"></div><div class="elementborder"><img src="img/elementborder.png"></div></div></div></td></tr>
54,57c53,56
<

.....
```

---

**EDIT:** I realize that this is most likely due to invalid HTML, my question was is there anyway in which I can avoid this as if you view the page normally in a browser the elements are there

More precisely I'm trying to scrape this: http://www.puzzledragonx.com/en/monster.asp?n=1

---

**EDIT:** I realized that this is also some sort of browser problem. If you download the page with wget and paste the HTML with cheerio, you will have a different html yes, but the browsers remove the tags when parsing the DOM which leads me to believe that cheerio/jsdom output funky html

I also run that page through the html w3 validator and there are a lot of errors regarding doctype not allowing an element to be placed at a certain position, but nothing regarding invalid markup

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your input HTML is malformed.  `$.html()` serializes the current DOM representation, which will not result in identical HTML unless the input HTML was syntactically correct.

To understand why this happens, think about what what happens under the covers.  Cheerio *parses* HTML text into a normalized data structure.  This data structure is what we refer to as the DOM: Document Object *Model*.  HTML is just a text representation of this model; after cheerio parses HTML, it discards the input text (as it no longer needs it).

When you call `$.html()`, cheerio must convert the DOM data structure back into a text representation of the document.  To do this, it recurses over the DOM tree and generates HTML for each node.  The original input HTML string has **nothing** to do with the output HTML other than the fact that the DOM was populated with input HTML.

At this point you should see why it is not possible for a library that parses HTML to later output the exact same HTML if the input HTML was malformed.  The parsing and normalization of input text is necessarily lossy: a forgiving parser *must* throw out HTML text that doesn't make sense.

You can see this even in Chrome: do [a diff of your page's source code and the string returned by `document.documentElement.outerHTML`](http://www.diffchecker.com/p5no12qx).  Here too we see numerous differences, especially around the malformed tables.  (Some differences are a result of scripts running and mutating the DOM.)  These artifacts occur for the same reason as they do with cheerio, jsdom, or any other HTML-parsing library.

Comment: do you know of any way in which I can avoid that, given that the html is most likely wrong?

Comment: myeah i got that, my issue is that this malformed html is parsed correctly all browsers somehow. I was asking if there is some way in which one can do that on server side. I get the html with wget so dom manipulation does not occur so theoretically there should be a way to parse it without altering as the browsers are doing it :)

Comment: Well sure, you can parse it, you just can't reserialize (`$.html()`) it.  If you need to mutate the DOM in any way and save it back to HTML, you're out of luck.  You could try filing an issue with [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio/issues) and/or [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2/issues) (cheerio's parser) if you think that poorly-formed HTML isn't being parsed correctly.

Comment: myeah, that's my issue cuz the 2 DOM's are different (the one generated by the browser and the one retrieved by cheerio/jsdom) even without serializing it :(

Comment: Your real problem **is** malformed HTML.  HTML parsers (both browsers' and cheerio's) are *forgiving*, which means they attempt to recover from syntax errors and figure out what the page author *meant*.  [HTML5 tries to standardize this behavior](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/index.html#auto-toc-12), but that's a whole book's worth of rules.  If the DOM that cheerio/htmlparser2 gives you for a given HTML string is different from the DOM that browser parsers gives you, it's probably a bug in cheerio/htmlparser2.

Answer (score 1):

I came here searching for the same problem and (fortunately) I also found a package on npm named tidyHtml. The name is self explanatory and here is the link to it https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmltidy2. Though its currently inactive with last commit 2 years ago but its doing the job.

Cleaning up HTML is as easy as running the following function:

```
var tidy = require('htmltidy2').tidy;
tidy('<table><tr><td>badly formatted html</tr>', function(err, html) {
    console.log(html);
});
```

It will standardize the HTML and will output this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>badly formatted html</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using it in combination with cheerio and the results are quite good. Hope it will help someone.